# How to upgrade numpy without changing linux distributions in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, numpy

I have numpy 1.11 on my 15.10 Ubuntu machine and I need the same version on my 12.04 machine.  I am not sure if this is possible at all and do not understand enough of linux to know.

I have tried

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I tried reinstalling, etc. and nothing seems to work.  Are the libraries simply not compatible or is there a way to do this?

I don't want to mess with the ubuntu version because this is a shared lab machine and I am worried that other people's experiments could have issues if I did.

EDIT: When I run the upgrade it says that it has installed successfully but doesn't say anything about the version.

here is the tail end of the output when I run the upgrade:

```
types -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/random/mtrand/initarray.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/random/mtrand.so
Creating build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py
  adding 'build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py' to scripts
changing mode of build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py from 644 to 755

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/f2py to 755
Successfully installed numpy
Cleaning up...
```

When I check my version:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.8.2'
```

Comment: May I suggest accepting an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I resolved my Issue.  I will summarize the problem:

When I installed Scipy by installing the scipy pack it automatically resinstalls numpy 1.8 no materr what, even if it is just:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

What worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-numpy
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install scipy
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
```

I don't know why the apt-get packages are not updated, maybe this is an issue that exists.  Thank you all for your helpful orientations. :-)

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you run

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
```

?

When I run it, I get this:

```
Does it Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.11.1.zip (4.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.7MB 108kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.9.2
    Uninstalling numpy-1.9.2:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.9.2
  Running setup.py install for numpy
```

If you are seeing this, my next question would be: are you sure your paths are set correctly?

Comment: running "sudo pip install numpy --upgrade" it downloads a bunch of packages.  In the end I get:     Creating build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py
      adding 'build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py' to scripts
    changing mode of build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py from 644 to 755
    
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/f2py to 755
Successfully installed numpy
Cleaning up...

Comment: I posted the output better in my question.  it is easier to read.  I am not seeing what you are.

Answer (score 2):

I find it is more reliable and repeatable to manage your python environment using the Anaconda python distribution. Rather than using apt-get, you would use conda as your python package management system and it should work fairly consistently across platforms especially with major packages like numpy.

Comment: This was a helpful comment.  After investigation apt-get was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Could you post the error message you received?

The next time you are working on a project, you could use `virtualenv`. `virtualenv` will create an isolated environment for each of your projects with a copy of the python binary, the entire Python standard library, the pip installer as well as a copy of the site-packages directory. This way the environment would be local to you and would not affect the version of Python or its dependencies across all user accounts.

Comment: Are you sure Python has been installed correctly? Could you also try installed numpy via `whl` You can use this link - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy